# How to add a PaymentMethod in QuickBooks Online using PHP?

Tags: quickbooks-online

How do you add a `PaymentMethod` using the PHP Library?

The object `QuickBooks_IPP_Service_PaymentMethod` exists but doesn't seem to support the `add` method.

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method QuickBooks_IPP_Service_PaymentMethod::add() in ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you grab the latest code from GitHub:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

There's an `->add(...)` method in `QuickBooks_IPP_Service_PaymentMethod` now supported.

Comment: Awesome! This must be a fresh add. Thank you.

Comment: Sure is, just for you!  :-)